# How to read this JSON AJAX response

Tags: jquery

I am getting AJAX JSON response as:

```
{"UUID":"1234"}
```

How can i read this JSON response? I have tried:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);

alert(data.UUID)
```

Please help me in how to read this value. I am getting the folllwoing under browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: Depending on how the JSON came in, `response` may already be an object, in which case `response.UUID` is all you need. Impossible to say without seeing more of the code. If you `alert(typeof response);`, what do you see?

Comment: Its giving me Object i the alert typeOf

Comment: Then there's nothing to parse. Try `alert(response.UUID);`. But, again, without seeing the code that's receiving `response`, it's all a guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery AJAX calls - how to capture response JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084132/jquery-ajax-calls-how-to-capture-response-json)

Answer (score -1):

Since you tagged this with jquery, I'll assume that you are including the jQuery libraries and my response below will use jQuery.

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
alert(data.UUID);
```

Comment: How would this work in a situation where `JSON.parse(response);` doesn't?

Comment: OK, I see your point. I typically use jQuery.parseJSON, and didn't realize they were equivalent.